# How to do single list to nested list using python

Tags: python

I am newer to python. how do i form the single list to nested list using python. Any one please help me.

```
content = ['a', 29, 'male', 'cs', 'cs', 'b', 29, 'male', 'cs','cs']
```

into:

```
content = [['a', 29, 'male', 'cs', 'cs'],
            ['b', 29, 'male', 'cs', 'cs']]
```

Comment: look for `zip()`

Comment: Where did `f`, `32` come from in the second list?